# Tomcat 8 hangs randomly without any logs

Tags: tomcat, jvm, tomcat8

We have trouble with Tomcat 8.5 running as a service on Windows servers with 32GB RAM. Which hangs on our production servers randomly and we have no idea why it hangs. There is no Tomcat's log in "Catalina.out" or any application's log and there no JVM crash dump file.
Any idea or log to read to find why Tomcat stops?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a thread dump and figure out if that reveals something